Does $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}=1$ imply $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_1+\cdots+a_n}=1$ for positive real sequences
I am working on an exercise from calculus:

Let $\{a_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ be a positive sequence such that $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}=1$.
Show that $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_1+\cdots+a_n}=1$.

Here is my attempt:
Trivially we have
$$
\mathop {\lim\mathrm{sup}} \limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{a_1+\cdots +a_n}\ge \mathop {\lim\mathrm{sup}} \limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}=1.~~~~~~~~~(1)
$$
For the converse inequality, by definition of $\limsup$, for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists some $N>0$ such that $\sqrt[n]{a_n}<1+\epsilon$, hence
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sqrt[n]{\frac{a_1+\cdots +a_n}{n}}&\le \sqrt[n]{\frac{a_1+\cdots +a_N}{n}}+\sqrt[n]{\frac{a_{N+1}+\cdots +a_n}{n}}~~~~~~~~~(2)
\\
&\le \sqrt[n]{\frac{a_1+\cdots +a_N}{n}}+\sqrt[n]{\frac{\left( n-N \right) \left( 1+\epsilon \right) ^n}{n}}
\\
&\le \sqrt[n]{\frac{a_1+\cdots +a_N}{n}}+\left( 1+\epsilon \right) \cdot \sqrt[n]{\frac{n-N}{n}},
\end{aligned}
$$
however
$$
\mathop {\lim\mathrm{sup}} \limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{a_1+\cdots +a_n}=\mathop {\lim\mathrm{sup}} \limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{a_1+\cdots +a_n}{n}}\le 2+\epsilon ,~~~~~~~~~(3)
$$
which is larger than expected.

$\lim \sup_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{a_1+\cdots +a_N}{n}} = 1$  and $\sqrt [n] {\frac {n-N} n}$  tends to $1$.

I think (2) has $/2$ missing. When that is used , (3) will evaluate to $(2+\epsilon)/2$

Alternative way : We will convert the Summation to $na_n$ , then the limit will evaluate to $\sqrt[n]{n} \times 1 = 1$

As $$1=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_1}=\liminf_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_1}\leq\liminf_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_1+\cdots+a_n},$$ with $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_1+\cdots+a_n}=1$$can we conclude that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_1+\cdots+a_n}=1????$$

@Riemann Looks like my solution was similar to the answers there. Since it's elementary, no wonder that they are all identical but the solution provided by Sangchul Lee was more general, I had to upvote his answer :)

Maybe a quicker way based on your observation (if I don't make any mistakes...):
Fix $\epsilon >0$, and fix $N$ big enough such that $a_n <(1+\epsilon)^n$, for $n>N$. Use
$$\sqrt[n]{a_1+a_2+...+a_n} < \sqrt[n]{A + (n-N)(1+\epsilon)^n}$$
where $A = a_1 + a_2+...+a_N$. So
$$ \limsup \sqrt[n]{a_1+a_2+...+a_n} < 1+
\epsilon$$

Good proof. A minor addition to enhance understanding (at least in my opinion): Set $N_1$ such that $n\geq N_1$ implies $a_n<(1+\epsilon)^n$ and set $ N_2$ such that $A$ (as you defined) is less than $A<(1+\epsilon)^n$ for $n\geq N_2$. Then the inside becomes $A+(n-N_1)(1+\epsilon)^n<(n-N_1+1)(1+\epsilon)^n\leq n(1+\epsilon)^n$

@QC_QAOA Thanks, that's more or less so (the limit of the RHS is $1+\epsilon$ or using your ineq is also okay). I'm a bit lazy to fill in all details, but I guess the OP will understand what I intend to do :).

@LNT Your answer is very nice and deserved to upvote. What I care most about is whether the result can be improved to $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_1+\cdots+a_n}=1?$$Here is my reason: $$1=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_1}=\liminf_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_1}\leq\liminf_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_1+\cdots+a_n}.$$

@Riemann Yes, it is true just like you have shown :)

@LNT
Thank you.
